# "spawn.h not found" while installing octopress on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, bundle, rbenv, spawn, octopress

I have been trying to install octopress on cygwin. I have googled but no avail. I hope that someone can suggest a hack (no matter how complicated) to resolve this.

I followed the [octopress installation instructions](http://octopress.org/docs/setup/). Everything went smoothly till the `bundle install` stage. When I reached that point,  the installation quits with the error telling that it couldn't find **spawn.h**.

I searched and apparently spawn.h doesn't come in any of the cygwin libraries. I installed all the c++ libraries I could from cygwin setup but that did not help.

Can you please help resolve this?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/46 as it may help you.

Answer (score 6):

I think the gem that fails in this process is `posix-spawn`. For this, you could install the gem locally:

```
$ gem install rake-compiler -v 0.7.6
$ git clone git://github.com/rtomayko/posix-spawn.git
$ cd posix-spawn
$ rake gem
$ cd pkg/posix-spawn-0.3.6
$ gem install --local posix-spawn-0.3.6.gem
```

The explanation (from an [article](http://matt.scharley.me/2012/03/10/windows-cygwin-and-jekyll.html) I found):

> There is a bug in the version of `posix-spawn` in the gem repositories however that makes installing via gem impossible on `Cygwin`

After this, try `bundle install` again, it should be successful.

Here's a related [issue](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/46) on the GitHub project

**UPDATE**: I recently installed [`scoop`](http://scoop.sh) a command-line installer for Windows, a pretty easy setup. I installed Ruby, bundler and octopress without breaking a sweat. You should give it a try.

Comment: I believe that this is correct, except for the line `cd pkg/posix-spawn-0.3.6'. It should just be `cd posix-spawn-0.3.6`.

Comment: The lack of posix-spawn effects a much larger set of applications, and is a standard cmake test: